# Restrictions streaming a commercial(?) music video clips from YouTube in a mobile app

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am thinking to implement in my app a search option (using YouTube API v3) of a singer and song name and afterwards to display (stream) that video clip.

My code search parameters:

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
searchListRequest.Q = "Lady Gaga - Poker Face" 
searchListRequest.MaxResults = 1;
searchListRequest.Order = SearchResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Relevance;
searchListRequest.Type = "video";
searchListRequest.SafeSearch = SearchResource.ListRequest.SafeSearchEnum.Moderate;
```

The result of this search can bring VEVO clip of "Lady Gaga - Poker Face".
Can that video clip for example, can be streamed in a mobile app? or I need to harden the filtering somehow.

Assistance is appreciated to make this clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's enough to leave it as default"?. Enough for what? to avoid any potential bad results?

Comment: To avoid video music clips that are not  allowed to be streamed outside youtube, like in a mobile app.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui I improved the question to your request.